# Path over registry (windows)

Tags: windows, matlab, registry

I try to get a path over the regestry of windows. My Problem now is how do I get the Path out of MATLAB_ROOT_32?

```
    for /F "tokens=* delims='C'" %%i IN ('reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\Mathworks\Matlab\7.9.1 /v MATLABROOT') do (set MATLAB_ROOT_32=%%i)
            echo %MATLAB_ROOT_32%
            set i=
            rem GOTO Split1
            rem :Split1
            REM -- Split the result into MATLABROOT, REG_SZ and Folder using space as delimiter
           for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims='C'" %%a in ("%MATLAB_ROOT_32%") do set useless1=%%a&set useless2=%%b&set MATLAB_x32=%%c
echo %Matlab_x32%
```

The plan is to get the MATLAB Path in the Matlab_x32 variable.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set MATLAB_VERSION=8.3
set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\MathWorks\MATLAB\%MATLAB_VERSION%
set VALUE_NAME=MATLABROOT

for /F "usebackq tokens=2*" %%A IN (`reg query "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%" 2^>nul ^| find "%VALUE_NAME%"`) do (
  set MATLABROOT=%%B
)

echo %MATLABROOT%
```

Just change the Matlab version to whatever you're using and it should be fine. There are variations in the output from reg depending on the OS version, but this should cope (I think!)